# Using Wine to open Windows .exe

Tags: macos, windows, wine

I apologize for repeating my question, but it was suggested that I ask it on this StackExchange site instead of stackoverflow:

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860067/using-wine-to-open-windows-exe):

I have created a simple .NET 4.5 Entity Framework Winforms application with Visual Studio and would like to open it on OS X.

I have used Wine before to open .exe's in the past and am having difficulty this time around. I have downloaded the most recent version of Wine, as well as OS X.

When I attempt to open the .exe with Wine, nothing happens. No error messages. Nothing.

When I attempt to package the .exe with WineBottler, I get a popup that says "Prefix created successfully"; however, when I attempt to open the newly created file, again, nothing happens.

I am very new to using Wine and have noticed that there are WineTricks you can use, but I am not sure if that is necessary. Again, I used Wine before on a very simple app and it worked just fine without using any WineTricks, but I am not sure whether I should include them for this app.

I have googled for help, but have not found much. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason to use wine instead of mono?

Comment: Is the exe available for download so we can test it? Have you tested it on Linux? (Wine often works better on Linux.)